# Legal jurisdiction over cloud storage

Tags: privacy, data-storage, encryption

I work on software that is a project of an encrypted cloud, created to protect users privacy.

We use a javascript crypto library called [SJCL](https://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/).

Only the user has the decryption key. That means only the user will be able to access his files. Not even our team will be able to see what's going on in the user's space and we can’t get the user's decryption key.

Is the legislation of country where servers are located prevail over legislation of country where company is registered?

Can we launch our software in Estonia or Lithuania (servers + company)?

Comment: Thank you.  This is how all cloud storage should be managed.

Answer (score 4):

The law in every country where your service is available prevails. That means that if your servers are in Estonia, your file storage is in Lithuania, your company is in Switzerland, you are in France, you hold Thai citizenship, your users are in the USA and the signal transits through the U.K., Belgium, Germany, Canada and Poland then you are subject to the laws of each and every one of them. In addition, if China has reason to believe that the stored files contain matters relating to their citizens then they can take an interest. And so on and so forth ...

A country has jurisdiction wherever it wants to have jurisdiction subject to the limits of and its ability to actually enforce its laws.

What you are proposing is certainly illegal in many countries and you need to seek professional legal advice - not rely on strangers on the internet.

Comment: Most of those countries are actually exceptions : Estonia, Lithuania, France, the UK, Belgium, Germany and Poland are all EU members. That means there's primacy of European Law, followed by the Brussels Regime to assign jurisdiction. Switzerland is a borderline case (EFTA member, not EU, signed Lugano Convention)